# Can I install 12.10 on Ainol Novo7 Venus?

Tags: installation, dual-boot, android, tablet

Is it possible to install Ubuntu on my Ainol Novo7 Venus?

I don't want any tablet-version of ubuntu, because I like ubuntu how it is and think there is no need for a tablet-version (I know there is no tablet-version, but many questions after it).

So I want to install full desktop-ubuntu 12.10 with unity and everything, but I want a *dual-boot* with my existing android installation. Is that possible? If so, how? Is 16gb enough for ubuntu or should I buy an extra sd-card for it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't seriously know a way to install Android alongside Ubuntu dual-booted. It requires a complete change to the bootloader and is difficult to manipulate.

However I think you can install Ubuntu (if you want to wipe out Android by downloading an ARM image at cdimage.ubuntu.com. See http://www.ubuntu.com/download/arm

1. Download the images at http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/12.04.1
2. Place the SD card at your host computer.
3. Make sure the SD card is not mounted (just `umount` it if needed)
4. Identify the correct raw device name (like `/dev/sde` - not `/dev/sde1`)
   Run the following command to write it: 
   (replacing omap4 and sde with the right values i.e. just omap for a beagle image.)

   ```
   zcat ./ubuntu-12.04-preinstalled-desktop-armhf+omap4.img.gz |sudo dd bs=4M of=/dev/sde ; sudo sync
   ```

Warning /!\ Some people have reported issues with this method. If this doesn't work, try the following commands:
2. `gunzip ubuntu-12.04-preinstalled-desktop-armhf+omap4.img.gz`
3. `sudo dd bs=4M if=ubuntu-12.04-preinstalled-desktop-armhf+omap4.img of=/dev/sde`
4. `sudo sync`

16GB SD card should be enough to install. However as you install more and more apps and files it may not be enough. 32GB or 64GB is a good option.